# are hashed indexes in mongodb field-size limited?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

in our DB we have a large text field which we want to filter on exists/does not exist basis. So we don't need to perform any text search in it.

we assume that index would help, although it's not guaranteed the fiels wont exceed 1024 bytes. So that's not an option.

1. does hashed index on such field support $exists-filtering queries?
2. do hashed indexes impose any field-size limitations (in our experiments, hashed index is well capable of indexing fields where ordinary index fails)? We haven't found any explicit statement on this in docs though.
3. is chosen approach as a whole the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your approach is the correct one given the constraints. However, there are some caveats.

The performance advantage of an index compared to a collection scan is limited by the RAM available, since `mongod` *tries* to keep indices in RAM. If it can't (die to queries, for example), even an index will be read from disk, more or less eliminating the performance advantage in using it. So you should test wether the additional index does not push the RAM needed beyond the limits of your planned deployment.

The other, more severe problem is that you can not use said index to reliably distinguish unique documents with it, since there is no guarantee for uniqueness on hashes. Albeit a bit theoretical, you have to keep that in mind.

Comment: thanks. I think we've got enogh RAM at the moment and uniqueness is not an issue too. But I'm still kind of worried about the size of the field. Is it officially stated anywhere that size limit does not apply for hashed indexes?

Comment: @user1312695 Implicitly: [Since arbitrary length subdocuments may be hashed](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-hashed-index/#considerations), I'd say yes.

Comment: well, i think it does state that "MongoDB supports hashed indexes of any single field". Thanks.